# Can't move text with margin

Tags: html, css, position, margin, padding

I was trying to code my first template and I encountered with a problem. I'm trying to move my link(home/") with margin function but it doesn't move. But other texts I can move with margin. So why I cannot move some texts with margin function?

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    background-color:#353C3E;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

.header_content {
    width:946px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}

.header_content p:nth-child(2) {
    margin:-63px 0 0 100px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Montserrat;
}

.header_content p:nth-child(3) {
    margin:-21px 0 0 564px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#959595;
    font-family:Montserrat;
}

#header2 {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#40494C;
    height:62px;
}

.header_content a {
    font-family:Montserrat;
    color:#717B7E;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.header_content a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:13px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:Montserrat;
    src: url('Montserrat-Regular.ttf');
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="header_content">
                <img src="img/near-logo.png"/>
                <p>ILLUSTRATE.</p>
                <p><i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</i></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header2">
            <div class="header_content">
                <div class="link">
                    <a href="">HOME/</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline elements have no height, so you can change the display from inline to inline-block to allow the height, or in your case top margin, to work:

```
.header_content a {
    font-family:Montserrat;
    color:#717B7E;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/p29Xn/)**

Comment: note that ie6/7 don't like `display:inline-block;`, for them i use `zoom: 1;` and `*display: inline;`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it is a menu you are using, I would use UL and not DIV. So I re-structured it a bit to see if you like it

```
ul.header_content {
   display:block;
   padding-top:15px;
   padding-left:15px;
}
ul.header_content li {
   display:inline;
   margin:0px 10px;
}
```

Here is a ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2nC9q/1/)***

Answer (score 0):

## Because `HOME` is an `inline` element.

According to the [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) spec:

**8.3 Margin properties: 'margin-top', 'margin-right', 'margin-bottom', 'margin-left', and 'margin'**

Margin properties specify the width of the margin area of a box. The 'margin' shorthand property sets the margin for all four sides while the other margin properties only set their respective side. These properties apply to all elements, but **vertical margins will not have any effect on non-replaced inline elements**.

If you want the top (and bottom) margin to get applied, change it to `inline-block`, or use `position:relative` with `top` set instead.